# Parsing JObject for key and values with json4s-jackson

Tags: json, scala, json4s

How can I get the keys `scenario0` and `scenario1` for each JObject in my List?

poop is a:

```
poop: List[org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue] = List(JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki)))), JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki)))))
```

Code:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val json = parse("""
         {
            "address0": {
              "scenario0": {
                "street": "Bulevard",
                "city": "Helsinki"
              },
              "scenario1": {
                "street": "Bulevard",
                "city": "Helsinki"
              }
            },
            "address1": {
              "scenario0": {
                 "street": "Bulevard",
                 "city": "Helsinki"
               },
               "scenario1": {
                 "street": "Bulevard",
                 "city": "Helsinki"
               }
            }
         }""")

val poop = (json \ "address0").children
poop.foreach(p => {

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you need values and don't have fixed schema:
   `val poop: Map[String, Any] = json.asInstanceOf[JObject].values` returns `Map(address0 -> Map(scenario0 -> Map(street -> Bulevard, city -> Helsinki), scenario1 -> Map(street -> Bulevard, city -> Helsinki)), address1 -> Map(scenario0 -> Map(street -> Bulevard, city -> Helsinki), scenario1 -> Map(street -> Bulevard, city -> Helsinki)))`
2. If you need values and have fixed schema then [extracting of case class](http://json4s.org/#extracting-values) could be useful.
3. If you need AST: `val poop = json.asInstanceOf[JObject].obj` gives `List[org.json4s.JsonAST.JField] = List((address0,JObject(List((scenario0,JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki))))), (scenario1,JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki)))))))), (address1,JObject(List((scenario0,JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki))))), (scenario1,JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki)))))))))`

p.s. I omitted guardian checks for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want it like this, as as `JObject` for each one.

```
json.children.flatMap(_.children) 
res13: List[JValue] = List(
  JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki)))),
  JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki)))),
  JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki)))),
  JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki))))
)
```

But you may find it more useful to parse them to a case class with a library like [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/), play-json or argonaut. That way you dont have to keep parsing json everywhere.

Comment: Sorry but no. I am already iterating the List. Each JObject in the list, I want to get the JObject's key, which is `scenario0` and `scenario1`. So for `JObject(List((street,JString(Bulevard)), (city,JString(Helsinki))))` I want to extract `scenario0`. I'm pretty new to scala so I'm not sure how to do so =/